# Favouriting a picture in a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to figure out how to execute a "favourite a picture" method in a Rails app, which I am very new to, going from a JS/Meteor background.

The point is I have a User, FavPic, Pic classes:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  #some user oauth stuff would be here

  has_many :fav_pics
  has_many :pics_favorited,
    class_name: 'Pic',
    through: :fav_pics

end

class FavPic < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :pic
end

class Pic < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :fav_pics
  has_many :fav_users,
    class_name: 'User',
    through: :fav_pics
end
```

and here's my template:

```
<% if current_user %>
  <%= form_tag(root_path, :method => "get") do %>
    <p>
      <%= text_field_tag :username, params[:username] %>
      <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
    </p>
  <% end %>

  <ul>
    <% @mentions.each do |mention| %>
      <li>
        <%= mention.text %>
        <div class="row">
        <% mention.media.each do |media| %>

          <div class="col-xs-3">
            <%=image_tag(media.media_url, class:"img-responsive")%>
            <a href="#" class="fav-img"><i class="fa fa-star fa-2x"></i></a>
          </div>

        <% end %>
        </div>
      </li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
<% else %>
  <p>
    Sign in to be able to use the app.
  </p>
<% end %>
```

`current_user` is a user signed in through Twitter and `@mentions` is a list of tweets that has the username inputed in the form mentioned. `media.media_url` is a picture url that is associated with that tweet.

I am trying to get that link (or whatever way it's done in Rails) to add that media URL into the DB so I can list all the images at a separate URL.

Comment: Can you explain how the template is related to users and pictures? I can't see them in the template. Maybe you have some kind of authorization and so a `current_user`? Maybe `media` is some kind of picture?

Comment: @MartinM i updated the question, let me know if you need more clarification, thanks.

Comment: Your changes are not visible yet,. I try to check the history.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a choice: change the `<a href="#">` into a form, or have your action link include the url encoded url as a parameter.  Either way, you can still use AJAX to invoke the call to the server.

Your server would have an action on a controller that accepted the appropriate call to mark something as a favorite.  Since you don't have your `Controller` code listed let's call it your `PicController`  I'm also assuming your `Pic` class has a `url` property on it.

I highly recommend this primer: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html and the very basic http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html which covers how to do action links and forms.

```
class PicController < ApplicationController
    def favorite
        pic = Pic.find(params[:url])

        favorite = FavPic.new
        favorite.pic = pic
        favorite.user = current_user # however you get at this...
        favorite.save

        pic.fav_users.add(favorite)
        pic.save

        current_user.fav_pics.add(favorite)
        current_user.save
    end
end
```

The above code covers how to create the new FavPic instance and save it appropriately.

Comment: i have `<%= link_to "Favorite", {:controller => "pic", :action => "favorite", :url => media.media_url } %>` @berinloritsch

Answer (score 0):

Putting together that

- have a current_user, that want's to add a picture to her/his favourites
- pictures are identified by the url that is also the media_url in your template

You need

- an action to add the picture as a favourite, i.e. in the `pics_controler`
- a route to this action, since it's a data changeing action, it should be a POST route

so in your `config/routes.rb`, to define a named route add

```
put 'pics/:url/avourite' => 'pics#favourite', as: 'add_favourite'
```

and in your template change the link to

```
  <%= link_to add_favourite_url(url: media.media_url), class: 'fav-img', method: :put do %>
     <i class="fa fa-star fa-2x"></i>
  <% end %>
```

Then in the controller:

```
class PicController < ApplicationController
    def favorite
        if current_user.present?
          pic = Pic.find(params[:url])
          FavPic.create pic: pic, user: current_user
          # user and pic automaically have this `FavPic` assigned
        end 
    end
end
```